# Extract a value from a string file and converting it to int with Java

Tags: java, string, arraylist, type-conversion, int

I have a text file (test.txt) :

```
Bob, 12, 15, 20
Ruth, 45, 212, 452
```

With Java, I want to extract only the last element of each line (each element being separated by a coma).

For now on, I wrote this code :

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    String[] facture = line.split(",");
    
    int fquantite = Integer.parseInt(facture[3]);

System.out.println("Amount=" + fquantite);
```

But it gives me an error. The thing is that I get how to get the number (for exemple, I can write :
`System.out.println("Amount=" + facture[3]);`

And it works, but for some reason, I can't get to convert it to a int. The reason I want to do that is because when I'll have this int variable, I'll want to add it to another int variable.

Comment: "But it gives me an error" could you add the error message so people with same error would be able to find your question and potential solution to their problem (which is kind of main goal of this site)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You split by comma, but your input also contains spaces. Use `trim` to remove them: `Integer.parseInt(facture[3].trim())`.